# Customising SharePoint 2007 Survey Pages with pagebreaks

Tags: 2007, survey

SharePoint 2007 Standard

I have a survey, which has been broken up with page breaks.  Is there a way to add introductory content to each segment?  As best as I can tell, there isn't a new ASPX page for each section, so a change to the basic form will show on all pages.

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve it by generating *introductory content* on the client side as demonstrated below.

Steps

1) Add CEWP into Survey Edit Form page

2) Insert the following content into CEWP

```
<h2 id="questionSummary">Please specify your development skills​​​</h2> 
<script type="text/javascript">
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}


(function(){
   var questionSummary = $("#questionSummary");
   var fieldName = getParameterByName('FirstField');
   switch(fieldName){
       case "Skills":
          questionSummary.append("Please specify your development skills");
       break;
   }    


})();
</script>​
```

Key points:

- during page navigation in Survey form, query string parameter
  `FirstField` is appended
- function `getParameterByName` is used to retrieve query string
  parameter, in our case `FirstField`

Results

[image]

> Note: The specified example is for SharePoint 2013 but the same
>   approach could be applied in SharePoint 2007

Comment: Vadim, many thanks for this.  Just to clarify in my own mind, I'm going to need to add additional switching statements for any new page that I want to generate introductory content for?  And the parameter to use, as in the case="skills" is the one that appears in the URL after the "FirstField=" text?

Comment: Steven, that's correct.

Comment: I see how it works now.  For the benefit of anyone else reading this the SharePoint 2007 GUI doesn't allow you to customise the EditPage.aspx in surveys.  Or Team Sites don't at least.  SharePoint 2010 / SharePoint 2013 allow you to edit the EditForm.aspx